# moment.js shows wrong difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have a silly issue with time difference in `moments.js`.

**Code to get time difference**

```
var to = '2019-02-03 01:55:00'; //When counter ends
var start = moment(); //Current time, for this example assume is '2019-02-03 01:53:00'
var end = moment(to);

var seconds = end.diff(start, 'seconds', true); //get difference in seconds, the third params is to get not rounded, but since in toMMSS function I do parseInt is useless
var formatted = toMMSS(seconds);
```

**function to format seconds:**

```
var toMMSS = function (seconds) {
            var sec_num = parseInt(seconds, 10);
            var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
            var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
            var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

            if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
            if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}

            return minutes+':'+seconds;
        };
```

Now the expected output is `02:00`, but some people get `02:05` or `02:07` or `02:03` but the output for `'2019-02-03 01:55:00'` - `'2019-02-03 01:53:00'` should be (logically) `02:00`

**P.S. moment.js defaults:**

```
moment.tz.setDefault('Europe/Moscow');
moment.defaultFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss";
```

`var end` is also in that timezone.

I tried others ways of calculating the difference, but get the same result, it can be that on some PCs/Browser this is not accurate, if yes maybe there is a workaround to not rely on user PC time?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: i think your moment defaults seems to be issue, i just created codepen using timezone and it works fine - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/zewMwq

Comment: @NagaSaiA Hi, thank you for commenting, why you think is an issue? Also as I mentioned in question this doesn't happens to all users, only for some of them.